# How can I select GameObjects by through the UI buttons?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I change GameObjects by clicking the UI buttons in Unity?

For example: there are 4 different color cubes (red, blue, green, pink) in my scene, and I have given some actions to each cube.

I want to select each cube and do those actions by clicking on each respected button. [An example is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSFp8.png)

Comment: So add a callback to onClick e.g. in the inspector, drag the according cube in and select the method to execute. Where is the problem? https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button

Answer (score 1):

use the onClick() function to trigger some events.
First write the needed function in the scripts and then add the script to the gameobject. On inspecting the object you can see the onClick(). Add the respective function.

Answer (score 0):

Assign Each Cube a seperate script
pseudo code:

```
public class xyz{
public GameObject _Cube;

public void colorChange(){
//your code here
}
}
```

or for single script

```
public class xyz{
public GameObject[] _Cube;

public void colorChange(int index){
//your code here
}
}
```

Now Create (For seperate scripts)Buttons or (For Single Script) Single Button. In the Button we can have OnClick Function. just assign the script and select method you want to invoke thru button click.

If you are not familiar with Unity. Go See Brackeys On YouTube